# makefile Compile issue

Tags: c++, makefile

I have some trouble with my makefile
When I try to `make` I get the error:

```
no rule to make the target main.o
```

But I can't see my error, in fact it's a template Makefile that I have made few years ago, it's a `cpp` project.

(I have another error : `/usr/bin/ld: can't find Sources/: file format not know`, I think I made something wrong with the wildcard thing)

```
NAME = Pretorian

SRCDIR = ./Sources/
HDDIR = ./Include/

SRCS = $(SRCDIR)$(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ = $(SRCS:.cpp=.o)

CC = g++

RM = rm -f
ECHO = echo -e

CFLAGS += -W -Wall -Werror -ansi -pedantic
HFLAGS = -I$(HDDIR)
LDFLAGS =

%.o: %.cpp
        $(CC) -o $@ -c $< $(CFLAGS)

$(NAME): $(OBJ)
        @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(HFLAGS) -o $(NAME) $^ $(LDFLAGS)
        @$(ECHO) '\033[0;32m> Compiled Without error\033[0m'

all: 
        $(NAME)

clean:
        $(RM) $(OBJ)
        @$(ECHO) '\033[0;33m> Directory cleaned\033[0m'

fclean: clean
        $(RM) $(NAME)
        @$(ECHO) '\033[0;33m> Remove executable\033[0m'

re: fclean all
```

Comment: It's main.cpp, it's a cpp project

Comment: `all:` should be the first rule in the makefile, so "make all" and "make" are synonymous. Anyway, add an `echo "Sources: $(SRCS)"` and `echo "Objects: $(OBJ)"` to check the value of those two variables. Then check if the contents of `$(SRCS)` matches your expectations (and the contents of your filesystem). Also, remove the `@` characters to make your Makefile verbose, to check which commands are actually executed. Again, double-check if this meets your expectations.

Comment: I have echoed $(SRCS), but I didn't get all my sources, only the drectory "./Sources/"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to do the trick for me:

```
SRCS = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)*.cpp)
```